# Is there a way to force a variable to 0 if an assignment returns a null?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var btns = "(BTNACOUNT + BTNBCOUNT + BTNCCOUNT + BTNDCOUNT)";
int abc = db2.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT " + btns + " FROM CLICKHISTORY WHERE YYMMDD = " + yymmdd);
```

The query on the right will return a number or null.

Is there a one line way to set the value of abc to a 0 if a null is returned on the right ?

Comment: As an alternative to @hnegfatl's correct answer you can do that already in SQL using `COALESCE((BTNACOUNT + BTNBCOUNT + BTNCCOUNT + BTNDCOUNT), 0)`

Comment: Keep in mind that if *any* of `BTNACOUNT`, `BTNBCOUNT`, `BTNCCOUNT`, `BTNDCOUNT` is `NULL`, the sum will be as well. Judging by the names of these columns, I get the impression that's not what you want, that you'd want to sum (1, 2, 3, NULL) to 6. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [null coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) operator `??`:

```
int abc = db2.ExecuteScalar<int>(...) ?? 0;
```

If the LHS of the operator is non-null, it returns that - otherwise, it returns the RHS (kind of like a default).

Alternatively, there's [`Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d(v=vs.110).aspx), which do much the same thing but are more readable:

```
int abc = db2.ExecuteScalar<int>(...).GetValueOrDefault(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar returns `DBNull` instead of `null`,
you can check if abc is `DBNull` and set the value;

```
if(abs is DBNull) 
abc=0;
```

alternative, you can wrap your sql statement with `select isnull((original statement...),0)`

```
int abc = db2.ExecuteScalar<int>("select isnull((SELECT " + btns + " FROM CLICKHISTORY WHERE YYMMDD = " + yymmdd),0)");
```